# how to make full page refresh

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, browser-cache

i have an asp.net application on C#,
and i have a page to change the profile picture, 
But when i change the picture, the new picture doesn't appear until i press ctrl+f5, 
so i need to do some process to clear cache and "full reload" the page.

I tried the following code but it didn't make any thing

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30));
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

So i'm searching for another way to solve the problem

Comment: Is the name of the picture the same after updating the picture data?

Comment: The "correct way" is to add a random number to the end of the url as parametre

Comment: Yes, the name of the new picture remain as the old one, because the profile picture for every user i name it as "userID".jpg So the name the be the same for new and old pictures, and i can't change it

Answer (score -1):

if your page is called profilepicture.aspx you can do

```
Response.Redirect("profilepicture.aspx");
```

Comment: He did that, and better that you code, on this line:  `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);` The question is how to avoid the browser cache and force it to reload it